Excel chart does not update when data updates, if data update was triggered by change from another worksheet
I have a complicated set of Worksheets. They simulate the performance of units in a strategy game.
This is the sheet I view the results on:

When I change a stat of one of the units on a different sheet - for example, if I make infantry much worse at attacking - the data on Line 58 will change to reflect the attacking unit dying faster.

But the graph does not change. This is despite the graph reading directly from the data, and the data being a table.
I am sometimes able to force the graphs to re-evalute by

Selecting the line
Pressing enter

But sometimes this doesn't work.
If I manually type a new number into the data, the graph updates. This suggests it's able to respond to a change on its own worksheet, but not a change on its own worksheet that was driven by a change elsewhere.
I use several VBA User Defined Functions to generate this data. I was doing Application.Volatile but have since disabled this. Nonetheless, as I said, the data itself updates just fine.
